# Placing the content of one post in two side by side columns, newspaper style

Tags: loop, columns

I'm trying to place two columns side by side like a newspaper does and display one post's content within both.

[image: multy column newspaper article]

I've been trying to explode the content at my h4/90 words and echo the rest of the content along with its own markup but it won't display. At this point I'm questioning even my method. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

$content = get_the_content();

add_filter('the_content', 'multi_content');
 function multi_content($content){
 $columns = explode('<h4>', $content);
 $i = 0;
 foreach ($columns as $column){
 $return .= "<div class=\"column\" id=\"content-$i\">" . "\n";
 if ($i > 1) $return .= "<h4>";
 $return .= $column;
 $return .= '</div>';
 $i++;
 }
 if(isset($columns[1]))
    echo $return;
 // $content = wpautop($return);
 // else
 // $content = wpautop($content);
 // return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there are specific CSS properties for columns:

Here's what worked for my case:

```
.featured {
       -moz-column-count: 3;
       -moz-column-width:245px;
       -moz-column-gap: 40px;
       -webkit-column-count: 3;
       -webkit-column-gap : 40px;
       -webkit-column-width:245px;
       -moz-column-rule-color:  #ccc;
       -moz-column-rule-style:  solid;
       -moz-column-rule-width:  1px;
       -webkit-column-rule-color:  #ccc;
       -webkit-column-rule-style: solid ;
       -webkit-column-rule-width:  1px;
}
```

And two refs for several other ways to go about it.

[ADVANCED 2 column looping](https://spruce.it/noise/good-old-2-column-loop-in-wordpres/)

[SIX WAYS to use multiple columns](http://digwp.com/2010/03/wordpress-post-content-multiple-columns/)